# $f(t)-$a characteristic function. Prove that $|f(t)|$ does not have to be a characteristic function based on the example:

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

$f(t)-$a characteristic function. Prove that $|f(t)|$ does not have to be a characteristic function based on the example: Discrete random variable

$$ X: \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  1 \\ \ \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{2}{3} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \frac{1}{3}$$

$f(t)=Ee^{itX}=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}e^{it}?$

Well to be frank I do not know how to do such I have tried some one the following properties of characteristicc functions ($f$), but they apply to this random variable it seems, I'll type them out anyway, I might be mistaken.

$$1.\ \ \ f(0)=1; |f(t)|<1;f(-t)=\overline{f(t)} \\ $$

Since the characteristic function is the expectation of a certain function $f(t)$ needs to absolutely converge. I do not know how to prove such.
Though I haven't tried these theories on this random variable, mainly because I do not know how to:

**Theory A** : Function $f(t)$ is a characteristic function iff the following are true:

-$1.)f(0)=1$

-$2.)|f(t)|\leq 1$

-$3.) f(t) \text{ is continuous}$

-$4.) f(t) \text{ is positively definite meaning for every collection of real numbers $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$ and for every collection of complex numbers $z_1,z_2,...,z_n$ applies $\sum_{j,k=1}^{n}f(t_j-t_k)z_j\overline{z_k}\geq 0$}$

**Theory B** If $f(t)$ is a characteristic function of discrete type, then the distribution function is found in the following manner: $$P\{X=x\}=\lim_{T \to \infty }{\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}e^{itX}f(t)dt}$$ I'm guessing with this one all one would have to prove is that this isn't a properly defined probability.

I will very likely put this up for bounty.

Comment: Directly compute $|f(x)|$ for given $X$. What is it?

Comment: Note that if $f$ is a characteristic function, then properties 1, 2, 3 from definition A are satisfied by $|f|$ too. Therefore, show that $|f|$ does not necesssarily satisfy property 4.

Comment: thats what im having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is straightforward to see that $\vert f(t)\vert=\dfrac{1}{3}\sqrt{5+4\cos t}$. Now consider $$(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4)=\left(-\dfrac{\pi}{2},0,\dfrac{\pi}{2},\pi\right)$$
Then the matrix $M=\left(\vert f(t_i-t_j)\vert\right)_{1\le i,j\le 4}$ is easily calculated:
$$M=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} \\
 \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} & 1 & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} & 1 & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} \\
 \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{\sqrt{5}}{3} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and $\det M=-\dfrac{16}{18}<0$, so $M$ is not positive. This proves that condition 4 in theorem  A is violated, and $\vert f\vert$ is not the characteristic function of a random variable.

**Remark.** One can also consider $Z=(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4)=(1,-1,1,-1)$ so that
$$ZMZ^T=\sum_{1\le i,j\le4}\vert f(t_i-t_j)\vert z_i\bar z_j=-\dfrac{8}{3(2+\sqrt{5})}<0.$$

Comment: can you tell me the theorem that justifies this matrix's determinant being larger than zero equivalent to the condition of $4.)$ or that sum being larger than zero in other words

Comment: @BozoVulicevic, This is not equivalent, but condition 4.) implies the positivity of the determinant, because it is the product of the  eigenvalues, (which are positive ) so if the determinant is negative the matrix cannot be positive.